# OTP authentication in the softether VPN Client

Tags: vpn, softether

I setup the `softether vpn server` in my ubuntu server and also installed the `softether vpn client` in my windows machine.

by following this link.

[softether vpn server setup](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/7._Installing_SoftEther_VPN_Server/7.3_Install_on_Linux_and_Initial_Configurations)

Now I created the user in my vpn server manager

```
user: user1
```

Now I want to know is there any way by which we can connect to the `softether VPN client using` the `OTP authentication`

Right now it just get connected by using username and password. I want something like 2 factor in which it also ask for OTP.